# BigQuery - Is it possible to use 2 wildcard tables in the same query?

Tags: google-bigquery, wildcard

I'm querying a dataset in BigQuery and I'd like to use the table wildcard capabilities twice, adding WHERE clause conditions for both wildcards. Is it possible and if so how would the syntax work?

I'm familiar with the syntax when using one Wildcard Table, based on [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables). 
For example, a query returning tables from the first 10 days of May.

```
SELECT *
FROM `ga_sessions_*` ga 
WHERE ga._TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190501' AND '20190511'
```

What I would like to do is add a second wildcard table:

```
SELECT *
FROM `ga_sessions_*` ga 
INNER JOIN `CRM_Data_*` ca on ca.ID = ga.ID
WHERE ga._TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190501' AND '20190511'
AND ca._TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190501' AND '20190511'
```

I expect a syntax something like `ga._TABLE_SUFFIX` and `c._TABLE_SUFFIX`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the second query give you a syntax error? Or what is the issue with it?

Comment: Actually the syntax above works great, I had an error when entering table names from my Dataset. Feel silly for not noticing before. I'd be glad to edit the syntax out of question so you can get an accepted answer for it. Thanks for your comment.